# Where do I set user profile in my code for registered users and the users who are going to register in future using Mixpanel?

Tags: mixpanel

I have 2 types of users Registered and not registered. I am finding it difficult to find the point where I must set user profiles. One solution is to set during the time of registration. But then where do I set profiles for those users who have already registered?

Answer (score 0):

To set properties for already registered users just fire identify("identified user id") method with any parameters you want to attach to a user profile.

If you pass existing parameters - values will be overwritten
If you pass non-existing parameter - parameters with values will be added to user profile.